# Add action to UIButton when focused (swift)

Tags: swift, uibutton, tvos

Trying to add an action to UIButton when it becomes focused (tvOS).

I am using

```
override func didUpdateFocusInContext(context: UIFocusUpdateContext, withAnimationCoordinator coordinator: UIFocusAnimationCoordinator) {
       super.didUpdateFocusInContext(context, withAnimationCoordinator: coordinator)
```

and then:

```
    if self.button1.focused == true {
    //do something
    }

  if self.button2.focused == true {
    //do something else
    }
```

is this the best approach or will I get into trouble?

EDIT:

in your opinion is this correct or is there a better approach?

```
 override func didUpdateFocusInContext(context: UIFocusUpdateContext, withAnimationCoordinator coordinator: UIFocusAnimationCoordinator) {
            super.didUpdateFocusInContext(context, withAnimationCoordinator: coordinator)
            coordinator.addCoordinatedAnimations({ () -> Void in

                var previewPlayer = AVPlayer()
                let previewPlayerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: previewPlayer)

                previewPlayerLayer.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2-128, self.view.frame.size.height/2-254, 254, 128)
                previewPlayer.volume = 0

                 if self.button1.focused == true {

                    let videoURL = NSURL(string: "someString")!
                    previewPlayer = AVPlayer(URL: videoURL)

                }

                if self.button2.focused == true {

                    let videoURL = NSURL(string: "someOtherString")!
                    previewPlayer = AVPlayer(URL: videoURL)

                }


                  previewPlayer.play()


                }) { () -> Void in

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can know when a view is focused by one of two ways:

```
//returns bool whether view is focused
someview.focused 

//returns focused view, can return nil
UIScreen.mainScreen().focusedView
```

Any of those approaches is correct and will not get you into trouble ;)

Comment: thanks. it seems that when I add a sublayer if focused and remove if not is breaking up. Not sure why...